# How do I add permission for cloud watch log in my appsync project

Tags: aws-amplify

I am enabling logging in my amplify using below override api

Here is my code

```
export function override(resources: AmplifyApiGraphQlResourceStackTemplate) {
    resources.api.GraphQLAPI.logConfig = {
        cloudWatchLogsRoleArn: CLOUD_WATCH_LOGS_ROLE_ARN,
        excludeVerboseContent: false,
        fieldLogLevel: 'ALL',
    }
}
```

and I have added cloudwatch permissing for all resources in amplify-user.yml.
However these permissions are not updated in my aws cloud yet. Is there any step that missing to update ?